# the park layout vs the park

Tags: word-usage

My freelancer, who is a native speaker, wrote this sentence. I wonder if he used "layout" because he was describing the maps and not the park. Would it be better to remove "layout" and simply say "the park has been updated" if I want to describe the changes to the park?

> The park **layout** has been updated to include modern facilities, which
> have replaced some natural features.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your freelancer is correct. "Layout" [in this sense](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/layout) means "the way that something is arranged." It often takes a noun adjunct, so "the park layout" means "the way that the park is arranged."

Removing the word "layout" would make the sentence sound less idiomatic. The word "update" is most often applied to man-made structures, so it makes more sense to say that you're updating *the park layout* than to say that you're updating *the park itself.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That is to say, when you say that you update a website, you actually mean you update the structures of the site? Or I shouldn't compare a park to a website?

Comment: @newbieforever - To update the text on you website is to *update your webpage* (i.e. your restaurant does not serve lunch on Monday anymore).  To update site structure (i.e. which pages take you where), to switch from one web technology to another (Microsoft to Linux), to change from a textual HTML interface to a graphical interface, is to *update the structure of your website.*  The differences are very small and might not be noticed in casual conversation.

Comment: To "update" means to improve something by making it more suitable for the present time.  "Update a website" is fine because (unlike parks) websites are manmade. It doesn't actually need to be a structure, but it typically does need to be something manmade.

Comment: I would agree, the bandstand has been updated to an amphitheatre

Comment: "Removing the word 'layout' would make the sentence sound less idiomatic."  A little bit of Googling suggests that this may not be true.  I can find a decent number of examples of "the park was updated" but **no** examples of "the park layout was updated" or "the layout of the park was updated" or "the park's layout was updated".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. @WendyG, are you trying to say that when it comes to updating the bandstand, "layout" is not needed?

Comment: Updating the layout means changing where things are in the park or what things are in the park; updating the park could mean cutting the grass or something else that doesn't change what is there.