# how to use 'floor plan'

Tags: phrase-usage

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332731/the-park-layout-vs-the-park) about 'layout', I learned 1) it should be **the park layout**, not **the park's layout**; 2) **Updating the park layout** is more idiomatic than **updating the park**. I wonder if these two guidelines also apply to 'floor plan'. It should be **the library floor plan**, and not **the library's floor plan**? **Updating the library floor plan** is more idiomatic than **updating the library**?

> The library/library's floor plan has been updated.

Comment: The "park layout" refers to the drawing, "the park's layout" is the park itself. Slightly differently "the library floor plan" is a drawing, "the library's floor plan" could be a drawing of something else, held in the library. And then, "updating the library floor plan" means updating the drawing, but "updating the library" means the library itself. The actual meaning will of course be governed by the context. Are they standing in the library, or in the architect's office?

Comment: "Updating the library" probably means getting new books.

Comment: @WeatherVane, thanks for your comment. Since "the floor plan of the library" means the same as "the library's floor plan", could it also be a drawing of something else, held in the library? Is "updating the park" less idiomatic because a park may not be man-made? They say only man-made things can be updated.

Comment: @StuartF, thanks for the comment. I want to say incorporating new facilities like self-service machines and so on. Should I use "updating the library floor plan"?

Comment: I had edited the earlier comment. A park is always man-made. It is by definition an area that has been landscaped.

Comment: If you want to add more facilities to the library, then say "updating the library's facilities" (or "updating the library facilities", there's not difference). "Updating the library floor plan" is fine and idiomatic, but suggests you are concerned with where the facilities are more than what facilities there are.

Comment: Building blocks
A schematic drawing of an open door, seen from the top, with a curved line that shows a quarter-circle space on the floor that the door travels over when it opens
Floor plans use standard symbols to indicate features such as doors. This symbol shows the location of the door in a wall and which way the door opens.
[...] It is **a measured drawing to scale of the layout of a floor in a building**. A top view or bird's eye view does not show an orthogonally projected plane cut at the typical four foot height above the floor level. Wikepedia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "park layout" and "park's layout" are valid and mean the same thing. One could check which is more common but either is fine.

"Updating the library floor plan" vs "updating the library": The first is more specific. If you update the floor plan, you are changing the way furniture is arranged in significant ways, maybe even moving walls. But "updating the library" could mean getting new computers, changing the kinds of books you stock, or all sorts of possibilities. If what you're really doing is updating the floor plan, it would usually be better to be more specific and say so. But if what you're doing is getting new computers, to say you are updating the floor plan would just be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

updating the library's floor plan or library floor plan (drawings), updating the park's layout or park layout (in drawings).

It can be a possessive OR an attributive adjective. Same thing. *updating the park* would be renovating it and would not refer to drawings **UNLESS** you are working on the drawings with someone and the context is clear. The same is true for updating the library. It means renovating it UNLESS you are working on drawings etc.

floor plans can be AKA layout and refer to architectural or design drawings.

[floor plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_plan)

Comment: 'Layout ' has two distinct meanings, so they do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @WeatherVane They do very often. They don't when referring to furniture arrangement in a room.